# How can we handle serial number for multiple users in a SQL Server table

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

How can manage the serial number for multiple users to enter records.net at same time in one table in SQL Server?

Now for single user, I read the last serial number and show it text box. It's working. If 2 users insert a record at same time -- the serial number duplication error happens. What's a solution?

Comment: Is the serial number determine by a person?  Is the serial number a integer value?

Comment: What is the error you are getting?  Sounds like a locking issue...

Answer (score 0):

You can use an Identity column. 
Or, if you need to display or use the id before writing to the db, another technique is to use what I've seen called a 'Fount table' (although Googling this term doesn't come up with any hits). Essentially you create a stored procedure that accesses one row in one table which holds the current id; the SP retrieves and increments the id within a transaction. This way each id is unique. In the example SQL below, @whichid is used to define which table we are asking for a new id for; @n is the new id.

```
create PROCEDURE [dbo].[spGetUniqueID] 
@n int OUTPUT,@whichid int

AS

BEGIN TRAN
SELECT @n = val  FROM fount WHERE fountkey = @whichid
UPDATE fount SET val = @n + 1 WHERE fountkey = @whichid
COMMIT TRAN

RETURN
```

Comment: If the table holds the most recently assigned value, you could use the bizarre syntax: `update Fount set @N = Val += 1 where FountKey = @WhichId;`.

Comment: Neat! I didn't know you could do that!

Comment: A bit of an exercise in obscurity, but worth knowing.  More generally useful is the [`OUTPUT`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx) clause. It works on `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE` and `MERGE` statements, handles multiple rows, and provides access to _before_ and _after_ values (as applicable).

Comment: Thanks,I got it.i make a separate table for identifier,every user take the serial no from that table.

Comment: Yes that's right. (It's called a 'Fount table' because it's supposedly like a drinking fountain and each process lines up to take a sip)